# Mongo filter/find all elements in embedded array that match a criteria and return surrounding documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter, document

Basically, I have a Mongo DB with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "other_thing": "whatever",
    "annoying_array": [
      {
        "sub_id": "a",
        "thing_type": "apple"
      },
      {
        "sub_id": "b",
        "thing_type": "pear"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "other_thing": "whatever_else",
    "annoying_array": [
      {
        "sub_id": "c",
        "thing_type": "carrot"
      },
      {
        "sub_id": "d",
        "thing_type": "pear"
      },
      {
        "sub_id": "e",
        "thing_type": "pear"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd basically like to do something like `db.docs.find( {annoying.array.thing_type: "pear"})` and have it return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "other_thing": "whatever",
    "annoying_array": [
      {
        "sub_id": "b",
        "thing_type": "pear"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "other_thing": "whatever_else",
    "annoying_array": [
      {
        "sub_id": "d",
        "thing_type": "pear"
      },
      {
        "sub_id": "e",
        "thing_type": "pear"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123300/mongo-array-query-only-find-where-all-elements-match) seems relevant, but is almost 10 years old, and I know a ton of the filter/aggregation pipeline has changed since then.  There's probably a much cleaner way of doing it.

I've tried everything I could think of, from `find` to `match` and `elemMatch` but everything returns all document and sub-arrays for which there *exists* `thing_type: 'pear'`, not every element in the sub-array for which `thing_type = pear`.  Even if it didn't return the surrounding metadata (i.e. didn't include `other_thing`, etc.) I'd settle for just **returning every element (sub-document) for which a key matches a specific value**.

It'd also be nice to have the option to return each matching element of the `annoying_array` that matches as its own document, with the document-wide data (i.e. `id`, or `other_thing`) projected to each match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Aggregation Pipeline`:

- `$match` to find all documents which `annoying_array` contains item which `thing_type` propery is equal to `pear`.
- `$project` to specify which properties you want to return from the result
- `$filter` to filter only those items in `annoying_array` which `thing_type` propery is equal to `pear`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "annoying_array.thing_type": "pear"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "id": 1,
      "other_thing": 1,
      "annoying_array": {
        "$filter": {
          input: "$annoying_array",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            "$eq": [
              "$$item.thing_type",
              "pear"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working exmaple: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7bLcScBQv8c

Comment: Looks like this works!  I tested it out Compass having a `match` stage and a `project` stage.  Now I'll just need to translate that into Pymongo, but that's a different question.  Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could amend your answer to include if you wanted to return each element of `annoying_array` as its own document, complete with the document-wide metadata i.e. project `other_thing` etc. to *each* element that matches in `annoying_array` and return each one as a separate document?

Comment: Yeah, but you should create a new question for that because in this question you specified the output you wanted. So because of the future visitors create a new question and post its link here.

Comment: Here is the updated answer: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8XmG9VMzubA